# Euler circuit, Hamilton cycle

Tags: graph-theory

1. Is there any graph $G$ with $\kappa(G) < \lambda(G) < \delta(G)$?
2. Is there a graph which has a Euler circuit but no Hamilton Cycle?

$\kappa(G)$ is the vertex connectivity, $\lambda(G)$ is the edge connectivity and $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree.

Comment: I don't know the standard notation in this case, please edit it if these changes aren't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer but I recommend you to think once more and then look at the answers. IMO it is very important to try to imagine the graphs for yourself.

For the first part:

[image]

For the second part of your question:

[image: Eulerian but not Hamiltonian]

Comment: It might be good to have a look at here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexConnectivity.html